# react's useState does not sets new state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jwt, setstate

I have the following frontend:

*AuthContext.js*:

```
const { createContext, useState, useContext } = require("react");

const AuthContext = createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState();

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{
      auth,
      setAuth
    }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

So here is the global `[auth, setAuth]` authentication object that will hold accessToken and refreshToken via JWT authentication. The `auth` object is populated upon login from database:

*login.js*:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from '../api/axios';
import { NavLink, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from '../context/AuthContext';

const LOGIN_URL = '/login';

function Login() {
  const { auth, setAuth } = useAuth();

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || '/';
  const errorMessage = location.state?.errorMessage;

  const [user, setUser] = useState('');
  const [pwd, setPwd] = useState('');
  const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState('');


  useEffect(() => {
    setErrMsg('');
  }, [user, pwd]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (errorMessage) {
      setErrMsg(errorMessage);
    }
  }, [])

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(LOGIN_URL, {
        username: user,
        password: pwd
      });
      const accessToken = res.data.accessToken;
      const refreshToken = res.data.refreshToken;
      const roles = res.data.roles;
      setAuth({ user, pwd, accessToken, refreshToken, roles }); // POPULATING AUTHENTICATION OBEJCT
      console.log(refreshToken); // debug what is current refresh token
      setUser('');
      setPwd('');
      navigate(from, { replace: true });
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response?.status === 403) {
        setErrMsg('wrong username or password');
      } else {
        setErrMsg('Login Failed');
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <p className={errMsg ? 'errmsg' : 'hide'}>{errMsg}</p>
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" onChange={e => setUser(e.target.value)} value={user} required />
        <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" onChange={e => setPwd(e.target.value)} value={pwd} required />
        <button>Sign In</button>
      </form>
      <p>
        Need an Account? <br />
        <NavLink className="link" to='/register'>Sign Up</NavLink>
      </p>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Login
```

When the `accessToken` expires, the frontend send request to `GET /refresh` to get new accessToken. This works fine:

*useRefreshToken.js*:

```
import { useAuth } from '../context/AuthContext';
import axios from '../api/axios';

function useRefreshToken() {
  const { auth, setAuth } = useAuth();

  async function refresh() {
    console.log(auth.refreshToken);
    const res = await axios.get('/refresh', {
      headers: {
        'Refresh-Token': auth.refreshToken
      }
    });
    setAuth(prev => {
      return { ...prev, accessToken: res.data };
    });
    return res.data;
  }
  return refresh;
}

export default useRefreshToken;
```

Also, the request for `/refresh` is done automatically, via axios interceptors, whenever the accessToken expires (signaled via `401` http status for a protected resource):

*useAxiosJwt.js*:

```
import useRefreshToken from "./useRefreshToken"
import { useAuth } from '../context/AuthContext';
import { axiosJwt } from "../api/axios";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function useAxiosJwt() {
  const { auth } = useAuth();
  const refresh = useRefreshToken();

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestInterceptor = axiosJwt.interceptors.request.use(
      conf => {
        if (!conf.headers['Authorization']) {
          conf.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${auth.accessToken}`;
        }
        return conf;
      }, err => Promise.reject(err)
    )

    const responseInterceptor = axiosJwt.interceptors.response.use(
      res => res,
      async err => {
        const prevReq = err.config;
        if (err.response.status === 401 && !prevReq.sent) {
          prevReq.sent = true;
          const newAccessToken = await refresh();
          prevReq.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`;
          return axiosJwt(prevReq);
        }
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
    )

    return () => {
      axiosJwt.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptor);
      axiosJwt.interceptors.request.eject(responseInterceptor);
    }
  }, [auth]);

  return axiosJwt;
}

export default useAxiosJwt
```

The automatic refreshing also works fine. The problem is when the `refreshToken` expires. When that happen, the user have to login again, so that `auth` object is populated with the new refreshToken (I will show backend doing this after this). The backend simply removes the refreshToken when it expires (when hitting `/refresh`) and creates new one upon login. And the backend does returns correct new refreshToken. But that new refreshToken is not reflected in the reacts state (`setAuth({ user, pwd, accessToken, refreshToken, roles });`), even though is confirmed by debugging `console.log(refreshToken)` that is indeed is new refreshToken (so backend is working fine). So when next `/refresh` is hit, react send old refreshToken which is no longer in backend (was removed when the old expired). So why is react not reflecting the new refreshToken returned from backend?

Here is the firefox console (with added comments by me for clarification):

```
50362bcc-7ee7-47c3-88bb-6748b4475c67 Login.js:43 // this is first login so it returns currently stored refresh token from backend's database
50362bcc-7ee7-47c3-88bb-6748b4475c67 useRefreshToken.js:8 // debugging the current token
XHRGET
http://localhost:8080/user // asking for protected resource, but access token has expired
[HTTP/1.1 401  15ms]

50362bcc-7ee7-47c3-88bb-6748b4475c67 useRefreshToken.js:8 // again debugging current refresh token
XHRGET
http://localhost:8080/refresh // automatically going for refresh to get new access token, this works fine
[HTTP/1.1 200  22ms]

XHRGET
http://localhost:8080/user //asking for protected resource with new accessToken, works fine
[HTTP/1.1 200  55ms]

XHRGET
http://localhost:8080/user // asking for protected resource again (for testing), again access token expired (it has deliberately low duration for testing)
[HTTP/1.1 401  10ms]

50362bcc-7ee7-47c3-88bb-6748b4475c67 useRefreshToken.js:8 // current refresh token
XHRGET
http://localhost:8080/refresh // now the refresh token itself expired (400 status, chosen by design), so the user has to login again
[HTTP/1.1 400  20ms]

XHRPOST
http://localhost:8080/login // logging to get new refresh token
[HTTP/1.1 200  196ms]

7eef8b87-9be6-42e3-85ae-4d607ceb5e27 Login.js:43 // this is the new refresh token from backend (previous was 50362bcc-7ee7-47c3-88bb-6748b4475c67)
XHRGET
http://localhost:8080/user // asking for protected resource with new refresh token
[HTTP/1.1 200  50ms]

XHRGET
http://localhost:8080/user // but access token expired so going to refresh
[HTTP/1.1 401  11ms]

50362bcc-7ee7-47c3-88bb-6748b4475c67 useRefreshToken.js:8 // debug wrong - old refresh token, the new one was not setAuth'ed, dont know why
XHRGET
http://localhost:8080/refresh // so axios sending the old refresh token (50362bcc-7ee7-47c3-88bb-6748b4475c67), instead of the new one (7eef8b87-9be6-42e3-85ae-4d607ceb5e27) so this is the error.
[HTTP/1.1 403  29ms]
```

From the console you can see the new refresh token is sent from backend, but not reflected by `setAuth` in react. Why?

Edit:
here is backend controller so that you know what endpoints return. As I said previously, backend works fine,the `console.log` debugging proves that. This is only for clarification:

*AuthController.java*:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private AuthService authService;
    private JwtService jwtService;
    private RefreshTokenService refreshTokenService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public void register(@RequestBody RegisterDtoin registerDtoin) {
        authService.createUserByRegistration(registerDtoin);
    }

    @PostMapping("/login") // the refresh token is deleted if expired (done in authService.getUserByLogin, not shown) and recreated and returned (again as correctly shown in console.log(refreshToken)) so LoginDtout is {String acessToken, String refreshToken, Long id, String username, and List roles}, all retuned by this endpoint
    public ResponseEntity<LoginDtoout> login(@RequestBody LoginDtoin loginDtoIn) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                 new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                         loginDtoIn.username,
                         loginDtoIn.password
                 )
        );
        if(authentication.isAuthenticated()){
            return ResponseEntity.ok(authService.getUserByLogin(loginDtoIn));
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("invalid user request");
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/refresh") // returns only new accessToken, new refreshToken is obtained from login
        public ResponseEntity<String> refresh(@RequestHeader("Refresh-Token") String rtoken) throws RefreshTokenExpiredException {
        RefreshToken refreshToken = refreshTokenService.findRefreshTokenByToken(rtoken);
        if(refreshTokenService.hasExpired(refreshToken)){
            throw new RefreshTokenExpiredException("refresh token has expired. Please login again to create new one");
        }
        String newJwt = jwtService.generateToken(refreshToken.getUser().getUsername());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(newJwt);
    }
}
```

source code:
https://github.com/shepherd123456/authentication_spring_and_react

This is for those downloading the source code from the provided github link: when git cloning the source code and running backend (spring boot), spring entities are mysql tables (and the database of your mysql has to be renamed in application.properties of course). When they are created for the first time, there is table "role" (Role entity). You have to populate it with
`insert into role(name) values('USER'), ('EDITOR'), ('ADMIN');`
so that when user is created (registered), the role "USER" is automatically assigned to him. That's all. Also, the react app is in `src/main/frontend`, and you need to install dependency `npm i` and then started the `create-react-app` development server by `npm run start` (anyone who has worked with react knows that). There should be no CORS problems, since spring boot `SecurityConfig.java` is allowing `localhost:3000` origin, which is where react's development server runs by default. But as I said in my original post, the backend is not a problem here. I really want to know why is react's setAuth not setting new refreshToken upon login (when the old expired) and instead is using the old one. Because using the old one, which is deleted (automatically when expires), cause nullException of course. Because simply the new one, which is correctly creating HAS TO be setted in reacts state (via setAuth) after login.

Comment: IMHO the auth data is not something you need to react to, or update the ui to changes. If it was a ref it would so much simpler to handle the axios interceptors and tokens update (just mutate the ref directly)

Comment: I also have opened a PR in your repo if you want to test it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not ejecting response in your `useAxiosJwt`

Your code:

```
return () => {
    axiosJwt.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptor);
    axiosJwt.interceptors.request.eject(responseInterceptor);
  }
```

Both the time you are ejecting `interceptors.request`

Replace it with:

```
return () => {
  axiosJwt.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptor);
  axiosJwt.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
}
```

**Explanation:**

As you are passing states into interceptors callback, the values of states get snapshotted. Whenever these callbacks are called they will use the same old state that got snapshotted. That's the reason whenever a state change happens you have to eject the old callback and assign the new callback with updated data.

**Why was this working with the request interceptor?**

You were properly ejecting the callback of the requester interceptor that's the reason they always had the latest values.

**What happened with the response interceptor?**

As they were not ejecting, they always had the old data, not only refresh token, but if you logged auth object you will see that everything inside it will be stale data like accessToken and rest of the things.

Read more about it here: https://react.dev/learn/state-as-a-snapshot

Comment: Interesting. I do admit I dont really know what axios interceptors do when ejecting and why that was problem (because there was not ejection of response), but it fixed the issue.

Comment: I have added an explanation for it. Hope that helps.

Comment: this would require that whenever react state is used in axios request, because of the "snapshot model", there would have to be always some cleanup (ejecting), otherwise the state would be stale.

Comment: Yes, also is a general practice to flush any old declaration in case you are reassigning it again. In your case every time the useEffect is called it adds a new callback to your interceptor. So you have to make sure that you remove the previous callbacks. Another common example you might have seen would be clearTimeout used in useEffect while setting intervals.

Comment: Whats the usecase of setTimeout in react, when all the dynamics are handled by react's rendering. Never saw anyone using setTimeout, except maybe if a request take a long time but even then canceling the request is not usually the best solution

Comment: It was just an example that if you are using anything like setTimeout or setInterval you have to clear it, react won't clear it for you. And if we don't handle it then it can lead to issues. You can read more about useEffect from the articles written by Dan Abramov [useEffect Guide](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/), especially search for "function Article" and how the useEffect is declared there. Another is about [Making setInterval declarative](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue might be related to the way you're updating the state with the new refreshToken in the useRefreshToken hook.

In the setAuth function, you are spreading the previous state (prev) and updating only the accessToken. However, you also need to update the refreshToken with the new value received from the backend. You should modify the setAuth function to include the updated refreshToken as well. Here's the modified version:

```
function useRefreshToken() {
  const { auth, setAuth } = useAuth();

  async function refresh() {
    console.log(auth.refreshToken);
    const res = await axios.get('/refresh', {
      headers: {
        'Refresh-Token': auth.refreshToken
      }
    });
    setAuth(prev => {
      return { ...prev, accessToken: res.data.accessToken, refreshToken: res.data.refreshToken };
    });
    return res.data.accessToken;
  }
  return refresh;
}
```

This modification ensures that both accessToken and refreshToken are updated in the state. Now, when you call refresh, it should correctly update the refreshToken in the state, and subsequent requests using the updated auth object should work as expected.

Comment: No, `/refresh` endpoint, does not return refreshToken. `/refresh` endpoint is only to get new **accessToken** (thats what refreshing means). New refresh token is only obtained from new logging. So 1) refreshToken is already in the `...prev` and 2) it is not even returned so is not in `res.data.refreshToken`. I will add the backend controller  to clarify it.

Comment: In that case, since the backend does not return the new refreshToken in the /refresh endpoint, you don't need to handle the refreshToken in the useRefreshToken function. The refreshToken should only be updated during the login process.
The issue might be related to the usage of the axiosJwt instance

Comment: refresh token is not *updated* in useRefreshToken. It is merely *used* there for axios headers, need for backend to know, for who to issue new **accessToken** (again thats how jwt spec work). I am only using `console.log(auth.refreshToken)` for debugging to see what is sent in the header. The refresh token is *updated* only in login via `setAuth({...})`. And as `console.log(auth.refreshToken)` in *Login.js* shows, the backend DOES return correct new refreshToken. But the `setAuth({...})` does **not** updates the `auth` object, because hitting `/refresh` again, it is sending *old* refresh token

Comment: See the browser's console output I provided in the post to see the steps (with comments claryfying it)

Comment: If the setAuth function is not updating the auth object as expected, it could be due to the asynchronous nature of state updates in React. The setAuth function provided by useState is asynchronous, and the state may not have been updated by the time you call useRefreshToken again.

To ensure that the state is updated before making subsequent calls to useRefreshToken, you can make use of the useEffect hook in useRefreshToken to listen for changes in the auth object and then trigger the necessary logic.

Comment: This is not possible, since I am returning `refresh()` function calling the endpoint. So the lifecycle method `useEffect` is controlled by react, but I am manually calling refresh() in *useAxiosJwt.js* (calling api). In other words, useRefreshToken is a *hook*, not a react component and since I am manually calling that hook, `useEffect` is not applicable

Answer (score 0):

In your authProvider can you change your code to the following

```
const { createContext, useState, useContext } = require("react");

const AuthContext = createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState();


const saveAuth = useCallback(
    (key ,value) => {
      setAuth((prevValues) => ({...prevValues, [key]: value }))
    },
    [setAuth],
  )

  const [contextValue, setContextValue] = useState({ auth, saveAuth })

  useEffect(() => { setContextValue({ auth, saveAuth }) }, [auth, saveAuth])

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

and when ever you want to update the state you can do

```
const {saveAuth} = useAuth();
saveAuth("accessKey", "yourActualAccessKey");
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Please describe current issue and explain your code a little bit?

Comment: This is somehow not clean solution. I am using `setAuth` in multiple place in application and if I should replace it with `saveAuth` where each key/value of authentication object be set individually, would require big rewrite of the app. For example in `Login.js` I am using `setAuth({ user, pwd, accessToken, refreshToken, roles });`, in `Home.js`, this way: `setAuth({});` (basically emptying the state), in `useRefreshToken.js` as this: `setAuth(prev => {
      return { ...prev, accessToken: res.data };
    });
`, where I am using previous state

Comment: In otherwords, setting individual property of the state seems cumbersome, I cannot get previous state or set state to be empty object. I dont even know why to use `useCallback` react's hook, how is that suppose to help?

Comment: The problem with using setState directly using context is, it creates a new state reference sometimes and it doesn't hold the latest value. So using callback will solve that issue. But i understand your issue with replacing it everywhere. Let me give a thought and get back to you.